# What happens to the motor when the car is in "D" drive mode with brakes held on?

Tags: electric-vehicle

Typically the electric cars do not have clutch or gearbox. This means that for short periods the car be stopped with brakes (hand brake or foot brake) while the car is in "D" (for drive) mode. Releasing the brake the car creeps forward.

Common understanding is that motor should not be stopped to spin and energized as well. In the EV case, how this is mitigated?

Comment: Most electric cars can recuperate energy by braking on the electromotor rather then friction brakes (regenerative braking). So I assume braking in a EV is done by a drive-by-wire system where the brake pedal just sends a signal to the computer and does not directly actuate mechanical friction brakes (the computer can still do that if required). In that case it's rather easy to simply cut power to the motor when the brakes are pressed at stand still and the computer can engage the mechanical brakes to hold still.

Comment: why would the motor be trying to spin when the brakes are applied?

Answer (score 2):

This will vary from model to model but a simple solution is to put the motor into constant torque mode by driving it with a set current rather than a set voltage. While this will generate some heat in the motor and waste some energy, it will be low in comparison with acceleration or cruise. The solution is to set this current high enough to hold as the brakes release on a hill start.

Takeaway:

- Motors run at constant voltage tend to run at constant speed.
- Motors run at constant current tend to run at constant torque.

Comment: That might be the answer with generic motors and dumb motor drivers. In any real car the controller should be able to detect that the brake is on and not drive the motors.

Comment: @asdfex, sure, but there will be a transition at some point and that's where you'd want the bumpless control. I don't work in that industry so it's only an educated guess.

Answer (score 2):

In a conventional automatic transmission ICE car that doesn't have engine idle stop function, the engine runs all the time, and is coupled to the transmission all the time, and when in D there's always some torque applied to the wheels. When the brake is applied or the car is otherwise stopped, the torque converter is fully slipping and wasting some energy that way.

In an electric car, the traction motor doesn't have to continuously run to power the accessories, AC compressor, generate manifold vacuum, etc, as it would in a conventional ICE car. The traction motor's only job is to move the wheels, and is stopped when the car is stopped. It may or may not generate torque at that point - that's up to the control system. The AC compressor is electric, and so is the hydraulic brake booster vacuum pump. The latter is sometimes electric in ICE cars too - for sure when there's a turbocharger, as there's no reliable manifold vacuum, and when there's idle engine stop, for the same reason.

Both brake pedal position and the accelerator pedal position are used to control the motor torque. In D with brake pedal depressed, the motor torque is applied as needed to slow the car down, and when it stops, the hydraulic brakes are applied to keep it stopped. The hydraulic brake system is by-wire, meaning that software is in full control of how the brake pedal position is translated to hydraulic circuit pressure. It's that way at least in a Tesla.

At very low speeds almost all the braking is from the electric motor, and the hydraulic brakes are only acting to hold the car still when the speed is down to zero. As the speeds increase, an increasing portion of the brake pedal travel is used to apply hydraulic brakes. As the brake pedal is pressed down, the electric motor braking torque is increased, and when it reaches the maximum, subsequent braking pedal travel is translated to hydraulic brake circuit pressure.

Keep in mind that in every modern car with ABS, if the software decides to release the brake pressure, it doesn't matter what you do with the brake pedal, so while it's not purely by-wire, it's like by-wire with mechanical backup, and the mechanical backup only fuly activates when the by-wire system fails its diagnostics or is powered off (!).

Comment: ... but the question is at what point is the motor powered during a start with hydraulic brakes initially on.

Comment: @Transistor It's always powered, not necessarily producing torque. With hydraulic brakes applied, the motor does not need to provide torque, so the control system ensures it does not. Then as you start releasing the brake pedal, the braking function transitions from the hydraulic system to the traction motor. Eventually the pedal is released enough that the traction motor controller gets a non-zero velocity command if creep mode is enabled. Otherwise, it gets zero velocity command, and torque is applied to hold the car still. Since that wastes energy, the hydraulic brake is applied by the code

Answer (score 1):

Through actuator sensors, wheel rotation sensors, and/or control signals, the car knows when the hand brake is applied and stops the motor.

Comment: To paraphrase, "Computer says 'No.'"